# Initializing function arguments in the global environment R

Tags: r, function, arguments

I'm looking for a simple function to speed up my ability to write and debug R functions.  Consider the following blocks of code:

```
# Part A:
myfun = function(a, b = 5, out = "hello"){
    if(a>b) print(out)
    return(a-b)
    }

# Part B:
b = 5
out = "hello"

# Part C:
do.args = function(f){
    #intialize the arguments of myfun in the parent environment
    ???
    }
```

The function `myfun` is a trivial example of a bigger problem:  I often have a complicated function with many arguments.  To efficiently write and debug such a function, I find it useful to initialize the arguments of the function, and 'step through' the function line-by-line.  Initializing the arguments, as in Part B above, is somewhat a hassle, when there are lots of arguments, and I would prefer to have a function as in Part C, which takes only the string `myfun` as it arguments and produces the same effect as running Part B in the current environment.

Comment: You should be source()-ing code rather than using function to build arguments.

Comment: @DWin, putting Part B into a separate file and then source()-ing it is a great idea, and would streamline things a bit.  But it still seems like there should be a way to avoid writing down the lines in Part B, period.

Comment: Using RStudio I usually copy and paste, then just replace all of the commas with semicolons. Of course you could use word or another text processor that allows you to find and replace. Then you can easily source the one line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This only works for functions where all the arguments are defined. In other words, myfun has to have a value for a defined in the function.

```
some.func <- function(infunc){
  forms <- formals(infunc)
  for(i in 1:length(forms)){
    assign(names(forms)[i],forms[[i]],envir=globalenv())
  } 
}
```

You could add a qualifier to deal with the variables that do not have default values, but it may not work in all examples. In this example I defined all missing variables to NA - and you could change the definition. Note: assigning the missing variables to NULL will not work.

```
some.func <- function(infunc){
  forms <- formals(infunc)
  for(i in 1:length(forms)){
    if(class(forms[[i]])=="name") forms[[i]] <- NA
    assign(names(forms)[i],forms[[i]],envir=globalenv())
  }
}
```

You could also adjust the function and simply skip assigning the missing variables by using `next` after the if statement rather than defining the missing variables to NA, or some other value. The `next` example:

```
some.func <- function(infunc){
  forms <- formals(infunc)
  for(i in 1:length(forms)){
    if(class(forms[[i]])=="name") next
    assign(names(forms)[i],forms[[i]],envir=globalenv())
  }
}
```

Comment: Fantastic!  In your second function, replace `forms[[i]] <- NA` with 'next' and I'll mark this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reassign formal arguments there is a `formals<-` function. By default the environment in which it does the assignment is the same as that in which it was created, bu that could be changed. See `?formals` and `?alist`

```
 formals(myfun) <- alist(a=,b=4, out="not awake")
 myfun
#------------------
function (a, b = 4, out = "not awake") 
{
    if (a > b) 
        print(out)
    return(a - b)
```

You need to use `alist` with the argument of the form `a=` if you want the default to be missing.

}